# Quicker way to enter ex mode in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a somewhat orthodox way to enter ex mode faster, like with a single key stroke, instead of hitting shift-; for ':'?  Why was that character ever chosen for such a frequently accessed mode?  Often enough to be annoying I'll accidentally miss the shift key, start typing an ex command, and find I have a lot to undo.  Thanks for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set up your own mapping.  e.g.

```
nmap <Space> :
```

Now spacebar in Normal mode takes you to the command line.  However personally I don't find `:` hard to type.  You get used to it after a few months of Vimming.

Comment: This appears to be the best solution -- I guess I don't want to get too used to another method besides ':', I just wish another character were chosen, lol ;)

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to use just left hand and type Shift+q => Q

Comment: *cough* `nnoremap`

Answer (score 4):

rather than making a quick macro just to enter : you might want to automate whatever you're rushing to do all the time. Little tricks like this add up.

I find double slash as an easy leader. (a lot of plugins map single \ )

eg I have

nnoremap \\t :vert stag  <-- opens tag of current word  in vertical window

nnoremap \\g :vimgrep  **/* <-- searches code tree for word under cursor

nnoremap \\w :w

etc

Comment: Following your suggestion, I created the following mapping, and will add more for frequent things I do:

nnoremap ;w :w<CR>

Thanks.

Comment: The only problem with mapping ; is it already has some handy functionality for left and right motions you will eventually learn. Check out :he f and read down. Reading :he map-which-keys suggests ,  and _ Come to think of it I have a ,w mapping I created and never use :)

Answer (score 4):

Typing ':' doesn't put you into ex mode, it puts you into command mode.  I'm not sure if this is a default keybinding, but "Q" puts me into ex mode.

As for a faster way of getting into command mode, it doesn't get much faster than a single keystroke.  I would recommend just taking a little bit of time to get used to it.

Comment: Right.  This is confusing terminology in Vim.  In Command Line mode you can run Ex commands but you aren't in Ex mode.

Comment: I find `:` the perfect balance between speed and mnemonic suitability. I don't want ex commands to be as quick as some movement commands, like `;` for instance, and since the `SHIFT` is on the left hand and `:` on the right, it's as quick as one key stroke anyway. I think the only default mapping I really don't like is `^R` for `redo`. I always map it to `U` so that I can have `u` undo, `U` redo for really fast tracking through change history.

Answer (score 2):

I switched the semicolon character with the colon character.

```
noremap : ;

noremap ; :
```

So now, to enter Command mode, I just press `;` (no Shift) and do `:` (Shift + ;) for reapeating forward a `f` or `t` search.

Answer (score 0):

Finnish keyboard has `, ;` in one key and an other key with the symbols `. :`. I have these following mappings to make using them a lot easier:

```
noremap , :
noremap : ;
noremap ; ,

if has('terminal')
    tnoremap <C-W>, <C-W>:
endif
```

This way I can simply press `,` to get to command-line mode, and I can move to next/previous search of `f` with `shift-,` and `shift-.`.

[image: Finnish keylayout]